# Making SharePoint lookup field auto complete

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

Can we make a SharePoint field which is a lookup drop down box on the `editform.aspx`. have the functionality so that user can type in and select from the options based on the values of the types?

Answer (score 4):

Try the code in EditForm/NewForm:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({

        sourceList: "<sourceList>", // Source List Name
        sourceColumn: "<sourceColumn>", // Source List Column from where you want to fetch it.
        columnName: "DestinationColumn", // Destination List Column where you want to add it.
        ignoreCase: true,
        numChars: 2,
        slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to call SPServices https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max for the reply. But we want the field type to which we want to have type ahead as lookup and not as single line text. I used the combobox method from below.

https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

and it worked for my case.